# How to fix Bootstrap dropdown that is covering content to its side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap dropdown button that I would like positioned on the right hand side of the page.

The dropdown is to be of 100% of the page's width, and should cover any content on the page when it is activated. However, I have a large logo positioned to the left of my dropdown button which I want users to be able to click on to take them back to the home page. Unfortunately, part of this logo is covered by the Bootstrap button.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="logo" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: black;"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown custom-drop hide">
    <a class="btn float-right btn-secondary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Menu
  </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    .dropdown {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 99;
      width: 100%;
      top: 100px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-toggle {
      margin-right: 50px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu {
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .dropdown-item {
      padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: you want it to be  positioned below the logo?

Comment: No, I want the dropdown and logo to be positioned in the same place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the area of the dropdown changing its width.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="logo"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown custom-drop hide">
    <a class="btn float-right btn-secondary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Menu
  </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <style>
    .logo-container {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .logo {
      background-color: black;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .dropdown {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 99;
      width: calc(100% - 320px);
      top: 100px;
      right: 0px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-toggle {
      margin-right: 50px;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 999;
      width: calc(100% + 320px);
    }
    
    .dropdown-item {
      padding: 0.75rem 1.5rem;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want the dropdown to always be 100% in width, but this answer doesn't work anyway, there is still part of the linked image blocked.

Comment: Oh, now I got what you want, sorry. I have fixed the snippet.

Comment: This still didn't fix my problem, the logo link is now all over the page